# Связи между классами в UML

Tags: ооп, uml

В чем отличие реализации в программном коде отношения ассоциации от агрегации и композиции?

Comment: Тут рассказывают с объяснением http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvyfqL6NwiM

Comment: Тут можно почитать конкретно про агрегацию и композицию. http://book.uml3.ru/sec_3_3#p5 Тут про отношения, где рассказывается в том числе про ассоциации.
http://book.uml3.ru/sec_1_4#p2